# create RDF using defined OWL ontology

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, protege

I'm generating RDF for a database table(s). I generated OWL ontology for the table(s) using Protégé. I want to use this OWL ontology and create the RDF in RDF/XML format for table data using Jena.  I know how to read and write RDF and OWL files into memory to generate Models, and I know how to use Resource, Property, ModelFactory, etc., classes to generate RDF.  What I'm unable to do is use the ontology (OWL file) I generated and create the RDF instances for those OWL class(s). For example:

sample OWL:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="Person"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="Animal"/>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="salary">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="Person"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;real"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

desired RDF:

```xml
<Person rdf:about="Jack">
  <salary>1234</salary> 
</Person>
```

I'm able to generate RDF like this:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="Jack">
  <ns:salary>2004</ns:salary>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: actually i dont understand what you want. Do you want to create individuals using your ontology?

Comment: I'm not aware of 'individual' concept. I'll check that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: In your example, "Jack" is an individual.  Also, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  You seem a bit confused about the distinctions between RDF & OWL, so perhaps if you describe what you want to achieve, we might be able to give you more directed information.

Comment: @Michael I'm trying to generate RDF/XML for the database table data as mentioned above. So I need to use the ontology and create individuals (probably each for each row in the table).

Comment: @Michael I'm able to create individual(s) and add properties to them. But when I try to serialize them using write() method, it's serializing the whole OWL ontology along with the individuals. As I already have an ontology I would like to serialize the individuals I create. Any help on this.

Comment: Are you using a relational database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is a so called RDB2RDF mapper. Try [D2RQ](https://github.com/d2rq/d2rq), a Java-based RDB2RDF mapper, for example.

Disclaimer: I'm co-chair of the W3C [RDB2RDF](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/) Working Group and my group is heavily contributing to the development of D2RQ - there are a number of other [implementations](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/wiki/Implementations) in various languages available as well.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between your desired output and the output that you are creating now is the presence of the triple `:Jack rdf:type :Person` (and, if you desire, defining the default namespace so that you don't need the `ns:` prefix on your XML elements).

Starting with your RDF

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="Jack">
  <ns:salary>2004</ns:salary>
</rdf:Description>
```

and adding the triple `Jack rdf:type Person`, you would have

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="Jack">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="Person"/>
  <ns:salary>2004</ns:salary>
</rdf:Description>
```

The RDF/XML specification allows for a shorthand notation for `rdf:type` triples;  if the URI for the type can be shorted to an XML name, then it can be used as the element name.  Using this shorthand, you have

```xml
<ns:Person rdf:about="Jack">
  <ns:salary>2004</ns:salary>
</ns:Person>
```

which is your desired output, unless the prefix is really important.  If it is, then you just need to use [`PrefixMapping#setNsPrefix`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/shared/PrefixMapping.html#setNsPrefix%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to set a prefix.  (`Model` implements `PrefixMapping`.)

```java
model.setNsPrefix( "", "http://yourontologies.com/thisOntology#" );
```

and you'll get

```xml
<Person rdf:about="Jack">
  <salary>2004</salary>
</Person>
```

when you serialize the model.